# Calling to another eureka client from @configuration class fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I want to call to hello service (using Netflix Eureka) with (loadBalanced) restTemplate from @Configuration class, but I get an error:

> I/O error on POST request for "http://hello/": hello; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: hello

If I do the same call on demand - It works.

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired  //It's load balanced in a separate config class
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    private String callToHelloService() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Map body = new HashMap<String, String>();
        body.put("hello", "world");

        HttpEntity<Map> entity = new HttpEntity<Map>(body, headers);

        HttpStatus status;

        try {
            status = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://hello/", entity, String.class).getStatusCode();
            System.out.print("\nCommunication succeed! status: " + status.value() + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `@DependsOn` on your configuration class so that it depends on load balanced config class?

Comment: I've tried it, not working..

Comment: Actually I see the log "Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server" after the error I listed... I need to find a way (probably) to run my bean creation after getting Eureka registry.